On a lemma in Mukai's book (convolution product relation in SL(2))
I am reading "An introduction to invariants and moduli" by Mukai and I cannot make sense of Lemma 4.57. The book goes back quite a bit in its notation, so it is not feasible for me to write up the whole notation, but I am happy to add more as needed by people commenting on the comments.
The Lemma says: In the distribution algebra $\mathcal H(SL(2))$, the following relation holds:
$$e\star f-f\star e=h.$$
and the $a\star b$ is the convolution product product defined as composition
$$A\longrightarrow A\otimes A \longrightarrow k\otimes k \cong k$$
where the first map is the coproduct on $SL(2)$ and the second map is tensor product of $a$ and $b$ (Definition 4.22).
The proof of the lemma asks us to consider matrices
$$X=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\
c & d\end{pmatrix},\qquad X'=\begin{pmatrix} a' & b'\\
c' & d'\end{pmatrix}$$
and claims that, by definition of the convolution product, the element $e\star f$ evaluated on a polynomial $F(X)$ on $a,b,c,d$ gives
$$\frac{\partial^2F(XX')}{\partial b \partial c'}\Big|_{X=X'=I}.$$
Then claims this is equal to
$$\frac{\partial^2F(X)}{\partial b \partial c}\Big|_{X=I}+\frac{\partial F(X)}{\partial a}\Big|_{X=I}.$$
I don't understand any of this. For instance, how does $X'$ disappear in the second line? How does one actually obtain the first line from $e$ and $f$? Up to where I can tell, there is no definition of how any element of the distribution algebra acts on arbitrary matrices or polynomials of matrices. Could someone explain how to realise this $e\star f$ as partial derivatives of $F(XX')$?
